# Match Dropdown Selection Across Multiple Sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, drop-down-menu, dropdown

So, I have a dropdown list in a cell using data validation in Excel, which is simply using the List option referencing a range in another sheet. I have this dropdown in multiple worksheets. When I select an item from the dropdown in one sheet, it does not apply this same selection to the dropdown in the other sheets.

I'm wondering...is it possible to set it up to where if I make a selection from the dropdown menu in one sheet, it will apply that selection to the dropdown menus I have in other sheets?

Comment: Can you share the unique formula? Is it referencing just the range or the sheet name?

Comment: Can be handled using VBA if that is an option?

Comment: @MarkS. it's just referencing a range in another sheet. And sorry, there is not a UNIQUE in there. It's just =PLs!$F$2:$F$19. PLs is the name of the sheet the list is in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a VBA solution:

- name all cells with the according dropdownlist "selectXXX" - be careful to apply the name on worksheet level using Name Manager.
- then add the following code to the `ThisWorkbook` module:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cTarget As Range: Set cTarget = Target.Cells(1, 1)
If hasName(cTarget, "selectXXX") Then
    updateSelection cTarget
End If
End Sub

Private Function hasName(rg As Range, strName As String) As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
If rg.Name.Name Like "*!" & strName Then
    If Err = 0 Then hasName = True
End If
End Function
```

This code gets triggered whenever you change a cell on one of the sheets.
If the cell is the cell containing the validation list `updateSelection` is called.

- Place the following code into a "normal" module:

```vb
Public Sub updateSelection(rgSource As Range)

Dim strName As String
strName = Split(rgSource.Name.Name, "!")(1)

Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Set wsSource = rgSource.Parent

Dim ws As Worksheet, rgTarget As Range
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not ws Is wsSource Then
        If tryGetRangeByName(strName, ws, rgTarget) = True Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                rgTarget.Value = rgSource.Value
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub

Private Function tryGetRangeByName(strName As String, ws As Worksheet, _
    ByRef rg As Range) As Boolean

On Error Resume Next
Set rg = ws.Range(strName)
If Err = 0 Then tryGetRangeByName = True
On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

`updateSelection` checks every sheet for a range with the same name passed and if found sets the value.

Comment: Excel doesn't allow me to name the cell the same value across worksheets. When I try naming it the same, it jumps to the named cell in the other sheet.

Comment: That's why I wrote to be careful to apply it per worksheet. You have to use the Name-Manager for this!

Comment: @ike: if you use `Worksheet_Change` then you will have to put the code in all the worksheets. A better option would be to use `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` in `ThisWorbook`  :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout: yes - that is true!

Comment: I updated the code to use the Workbook_SheetChange-event plus some updates to `UpdateSelection`

Comment: Works nicely :)

Comment: Ok, I need to set this up and test it out.

Comment: How can I reference all of the cells from different sheets in Name Manager, and name them as the same name? Do I add plus signs after each one? Seems like adding a plus sign after each one in the Refers to box is the only way to do it. But not sure if I'm doing this right.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. I need to change the Scope to each sheet. Nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the selection to control the other data validation cells there's a few ways to accomplish this short of VBA, but some sacrifices may have to be made.

First and most important, this won't be multi-directional, meaning it will require deciding one of the data validations will serve as the master-selection.

First, in the Mastercell select an option that is accepted by the other validations, and you can keep the validations in those cells and point it to the first. Unless the Mastercell is blank, this shouldn't produce an error as the validation will accept the selection. Deleting the selection will result in a "0" in the other validations but it won't produce a prompt-error.

You can shut off the validations and point them to the selection cell to control all of them. The sacrifice of these choices is you won't be able to put the selection in any and have them control the rest. That will require VBA as it overwrites the formulas that would populate the cell values.